# Storing records in a for loop array and displaying them

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to create a program that generates plane tickets and after that it asks the user if they want to see the passenger list.

What I am struggling with is that after every user that has input their details, they must get added to the passenger list.
So if User1 enters his details and must get asked if they want to see the passenger list (so far there will be only one record under the passenger list), then wen User2 enters his details it must ask the user if they want to see the passenger list and the User2 details must get added to the passenger list (so we will have 2 records under the passenger list) and so on..

Please assist with that.

```
public class Question12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
               double random = Math.random()* 69 + 1;
               String q;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] PlaneTicket = new String[3][3];

       for (int row = 0; row < 67; row++) {


           System.out.print("Enter name:");        
           PlaneTicket[row][0] = in.next();

           System.out.print("Enter surname: ");
           PlaneTicket[row][1] = in.next();


           System.out.print("Enter a ID: ");
           PlaneTicket[row][2] = in.next();

           System.out.println("************Airport**********");
           System.out.println("Seat number: " +  Math.round(random));
           System.out.println("Name: " + PlaneTicket[row][0]);
           System.out.println("Surname: " + PlaneTicket[row][1]);
           System.out.println("ID: " + PlaneTicket[row][2]);
           System.out.println("*****************************");

           System.out.println("Do you want to view the passanger list: " + "(Yes/No)");
           q = in.next();

          if ("Yes".equals(q))  {
           System.out.println("Name     Surname     ID     Seat Number");
           System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
           System.out.println(PlaneTicket[row][0]+"    "+PlaneTicket[row][1]+"      "+PlaneTicket[row][2]+ "    "+ Math.round(random));
```

Comment: Your code is cut off at the bottom...

Comment: here your case you can store only first 3-passanger info then after you will get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: Sorry, that is all the code i have. It is just missing a bracket.

Comment: It misses at least 3 brackets!? if, for, and main-method.

Comment: @Lyubo On a side note: use *shall* for fundamental requirements instead of *must* and *should* for nice-to-be-there requirements. I edited your question.

Comment: Hi All, as I mentined earlier, this code have Exception, please do some meaning ful work on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print all the entered values so far, you can do:

```
System.out.println("Name     Surname     ID     Seat Number");
System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

for (int k = 0; k <= row; k++) {   
    System.out.println(PlaneTicket[k][0] + "    " + PlaneTicket[k][1] + "      " + PlaneTicket[k][2] + "    " + Math.round(random));
}
```

Does that answer your question?

**Some remarks**:

- you have to fix the array size (as mentioned in the comments): `String[][] PlaneTicket = new String[67][3];`
- you should create a class `PassengerTicket`, which would help to make your code more readable (and more object-oriented)
- you should redesign your code to utilize methods for the different operations you have (add, print, ...)
- your output should be formatted (e.g., using `String.format`)
- you should have a look at `Collections`, which would make your code more readable and probably easier to  maintain, i.e., https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Here is your main method with some fixes, as mentioned please do some redesign (see my remarks):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int maxPassengers = 67;

    double random = Math.random() * 69 + 1;
    String q;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[][] PlaneTicket = new String[maxPassengers][4];

    for (int row = 0; row < maxPassengers; row++) {
        System.out.print("Enter name:");
        PlaneTicket[row][0] = in.next();

        System.out.print("Enter surname: ");
        PlaneTicket[row][1] = in.next();

        System.out.print("Enter a ID: ");
        PlaneTicket[row][2] = in.next();

        // you should keep the SeatNumber
        PlaneTicket[row][3] = String.valueOf(Math.round(random));

        System.out.println("************Airport**********");
        System.out.println("Seat number: " + PlaneTicket[row][3]);
        System.out.println("Name: " + PlaneTicket[row][0]);
        System.out.println("Surname: " + PlaneTicket[row][1]);
        System.out.println("ID: " + PlaneTicket[row][2]);
        System.out.println("*****************************");

        System.out.println("Do you want to view the passanger list: " + "(Yes/No)");
        q = in.next();

        if ("Yes".equalsIgnoreCase(q) || "y".equalsIgnoreCase(q)) {
            System.out.println("Name     Surname     ID     Seat Number");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

            for (int k = 0; k <= row; k++) {
                System.out.println(PlaneTicket[k][0] + "    " + PlaneTicket[k][1] + "      " + PlaneTicket[k][2] + "    " + PlaneTicket[row][3]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just tested it and it works perfectly.

Comment: I did it, but since you added the remark about the array size, I revoked it. +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method `displayList(String[][] seats)` and call it once each customer types `"Yes"`. This method will have similar loop(s) and display the current list

```
  for (int row = 0; row < 67; row++) { ....}
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize a two dimensional array `PlaneTicket = new String[3][3]` and the you run it up to 66.. that clearly gives an `IndexOutOfBounds Exception`. Best way, avoid magic numbers and put them in a variable such as `row` or `column` and then iterate up to it.

Otherwise it looks OK.

Second, be careful with the terms *list* and *array*. Do you mean Passenger*list* or just an *array*?

It seems you have it at the bottom, but you miss some brackets. After fixing the indexing, it should work.